# How to hide portlet in liferay by using javascript

Tags: liferay

Actually on a single page I have 2 portlet but I want to hide the first portlet by clicking the `submit` button and only the second portlet should be visible I used the following code:

```
document.getElementById("portlet-id").style.visibility='none'
```

But after refreshing the page, again portlet is visible can anyone provide me the solution as to how I can proceed.

Comment: Will it be possible to tell in which portlet is the `submit` button?
Why do you want to do it only through javascript?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can set the `visibility` of the portlet to `false` in the JSP by using the following code:

```java
<%
renderRequest.setAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_CONFIGURATOR_VISIBILITY, Boolean.FALSE);
%>
```

This would hide your portlet from user's view.

Everytime your portlet is rendered you can check a parameter which was set in the request or session (your choice) to either show the portlet or not show the portlet, like:

```java
<%
String paramFromRequestToHide = renderRequest.getParameter("hidePortlet");
// can also fetch from session: portletSession.getAttribute("hidePortlet");

if (paramFromRequestToHide .equals("YES")) { // you can use your favorite data-type
    renderRequest.setAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_CONFIGURATOR_VISIBILITY, Boolean.FALSE);
} else {
    renderRequest.setAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_CONFIGURATOR_VISIBILITY, Boolean.TRUE);
}
%>
```

---

#### Another method:

---

If you don't want to go with the above approach then you can combine your javascript approach with the parameter approach as follows:

```java
<%
String paramFromRequestToHide = renderRequest.getParameter("hidePortlet");

if (paramFromRequestToHide .equals("YES")) {
%>

<aui:script>
    Liferay.Portlet.ready(

    /*
    This function gets loaded after each and every portlet on the page.

    portletId: the current portlet's id
    node: the Alloy Node object of the current portlet
    */
        function(portletId, node) {
            document.getElementById(portletId).style.display = 'none';
            // or alternatively using pure Alloy UI
            // node.hide();
        }
    );
</aui:script>

<%
} else {
%>

<aui:script>
    Liferay.Portlet.ready(
        function(portletId, node) {
            document.getElementById(portletId).style.display = 'block';
            // or alternatively using pure Alloy UI
            // node.show();
        }
    );
</aui:script>

<%
}
%>
```

<sub>In case you want to check-out [Alloy UI API](http://deploy.alloyui.com/api/) and some of the [demos](http://deploy.alloyui.com/) to learn Alloy UI since starting from Liferay 6.1 Alloy UI is the de-facto javascript library for liferay. Now Alloy UI has an [official web-site](http://alloyui.com/) with many helpful tutorials and examples.</sub>

Hope this gives you ample material to proceed :-)

Answer (score 0):

You also can do like this :

If your portlet id is : callcenter_WAR_xyzyportlet

$('#p_p_id_callcenter_WAR_xyzyportlet_').css({display:'none'});